# Google fit api integration

Tags: php, laravel

How to retrieve the user profile info using googlefit api? I want to store the user profile in my project. But i cant find any url endpoint for userprofile using Googlefit api. Please give a solution .Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you need something like [Users:get](https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/reference/users/dataSources/get)?

I think that is what are you looking for.

Comment: Not like that. I am integrated Gplus  api in my project .After authorization, i retrieved the user profile using the acces_token with Get method using the url "https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me/?access_token={ACCESS_TOKEN}.I am looking something like that